SDDM on across one giant screen
I wish to have SDDM stretch all 3 of my monitors. This way, I can have one giant art background across three monitors with the login options in the middle monitor.The code I have in the Xsetup is

xrandr --setmonitor SDDMVirtual 5760/1536x1080/864+0+0 HDMI-1,DP-1,DP-2 --fb 5760x1080

This works in my WM, and when I use the SDDM-Greeter test mode, but when it comes to a live test, it just does the mirror thing. My question is, a) is there a fix and b) if not is there a display manager that can do this.
